# How is scope working in this javascript example?

Tags: javascript

I found a snippet of code that I am having trouble understanding. If someone can take me through it, it would be nice. Heres the code, I will add my attempt below

```
main()

function main()
{
    var name = "bob";
    doSomething(function()
    {
        if (false)
        {
            var name = "fred";
        }

        // Were you expecting it to be "bob"?!
        alert(name);
    });
}

function doSomething(callbackFunction)
{
    callbackFunction();   
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
undefined
```

**My attempt**

First within `main()`, we set a `name` to `bob`. Then the function `doSomething` calls the anonymous function we pass in.

Now heres where I get a bit confused.

What does `if (false)` check? If what is false, do we reset our `name` to fred?

We then proceed to alert the `name`, which well... is apparently `undefined`.

Comment: did you run this snippet in a browser?  You'll only get the `alert` in the browser.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Comment: It's not checking anything for false. It's showing you variable hoisting.

Comment: I got `undefined` in a browser. and @DaveNewton, what do you mean? Whats the point of the if statement then

Comment: I'll read the other link, mabye then Ill understand

Comment: if false, then it creates a `local variable` name with value `fred` it doesnt update.

Comment: if WHAT is false? thats what I dont get

Comment: @bill The `if (false) { ... }` block just means "here is some code in the function that will never ever run". It is testing if the boolean primitive `false` is a truthy value, which is never the case. You could also write this as `var foo = false; if (foo) { ... }` but that's a bit longer.

Comment: On top of the code there was a description saying `If you define a variable in the outer scope, and then have an if statement define a variable inside the function with the same name, even if that if branch isn't reached it is redefined.`, so is that wrong?

Comment: The duplicate here is a little more complex than your example, so I'll give a quick, more targeted explanation: `var name = "fred"` does two things: (1) it *declares* a new variable in the local function scope, and (2) it sets that variable to the value `"fred"`. Think of it as two separate statements, `var name;` and `name = "fred";`. However, due to hoisting (see my link above), all `var` declarations are hoisted to the top of their scope. The `var name` part is lifted out of the `if(false)` block and *does* run. However, its value is never set (because `name="fred"` does not run).

Comment: How does `if(false)` run? Is this related to hoisting as well?

Comment: No, I mentioned above: `if(false)` is used here the same as `var foo = false; if (foo) { ... }`. (If you don't understand how that code operates, then you may need to review how JavaScript syntax works for boolean literals, variable assignment, and/or `if` statements; I cannot make it any simpler)

Comment: Ok, ill try looking at boolean stuff again. Your `var foo = false` example makes sense to me, its just that I didnt really get if WHAT is `false` do ` {}`

Comment: @Arjun No, it creates a local variable `fred` no matter what, but it's not initialized, because the initialization happens in the `if` statement body that will never execute.

Comment: @bill The `if` statement is `if (false)`, and that's all. `false` will never evaluate to `true` or anything truthy. The body of the `if` statement will never execute. Variable hoisting in JS means that the variable `fred` *will* exist, be set to undefined, at the start of the function's body: that's just how JS works. You're getting hung up on a simple `if` statement where the expression under test is `false`. The "point" of the `if` statement is to show you variable hoisting.

Comment: @bill An `if(...)` statement says "If `...` is true, then...", so therefore `if(false)` says, "If the *boolean primitive `false` as defined by the JavaScript language* is true, then..." That's it; that's the whole thing. The point is that the code inside the block will never run (since `false` will never be true)

Comment: So moral of story is if I reassign a variable already existing in the global scope, in an if statement. Even if the if statement is never actually true, javascript will reassign the global scope to be undefined?

Comment: @bill You're getting closer, but: (1) nothing is being "re"-assigned; the `var name` creates a new variable, local to the containing function (here, the anonymous function being passed into `doSomething`) and the value of a value is by default `undefined` until set to something else. The creation of this variable "shadows" the visibility of the variable called `name` in the outer scope, so it is not accessible. (2) This effect then is not global, but only local to the function.

Comment: OoOoOoOooOoOoOooOo, so basically `if(false) `is NOT true,but due to hoisting V8 interprets this as simply `var name;`, but since `name` isn't set, javascript sets it to undefined hence `undefined`? This is within the `doSomething()` scope.

Comment: @DaveNewton oh yes! Thanks for the clarification!